# Linux VMWare player installation "VMs are running" error

Tags: linux, arch-linux, system-installation

I was evaluating VMWare workstation lately but as my trial period ran out I decided not to go for a license, so I uninstalled the now defunct workstation 9 in order to re-install the player.

The removal went uneventfully, but when I now run the VMWare player installer I get an error message saying that there are still VMs running on the machine.

I have checked my packages and there is no other virtualization host software present. The VMWare modules are not loaded in the kernel and no other indicator exists that something the like should be happening (no unexplained network interfaces, memory usage etc).

What can be the cause of this false positive?

Some additional information: up-to-date Arch Linux, VMWare workstation was the first virtualization product in this machine.

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer rather than including it in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution:

delete all references to vmware and vmware workstation.

Apparently the un-installer doesn't keep a very good track of its assets so I   had files existing in

> /etc/vmware
>    /etc/vmware-workstation
>    /etc/rc.d
>    the systemd directories
>    /usr/bin
>    etc.

run a locate or similar looking for vmware and all unneeded pieces should become apparent.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to load vmware's modules into the kernel:

```
vmware-modconfig --console --install-all
```